# Printing Large PDF from Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf

When I try to print an attached over-sized PDF sheet (larger than letter sized) from Outlook, the print is cut off.

How can I configure Outlook to automatically fit the PDF to page sized without having to open it up in Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to change your default printer settings for the printing from Outlook uses the default printer settings (this is the case you usually have to print larger files then letter sizes directly from Outlook)

Comment: of course you can change the default paper size, but you'll need a printer supporting this size (e.g. an A3 printer), i think mrach is looking for a way to scale down the page size to match the paper size supported by his/her printer.